# Generate random points within an svg circle area in d3 or javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, math, svg, geometry

I have an **svg circle element** with coordinate attribute as below:

```
<circle id="c1" class="area" cx="440" cy="415" r="75"></circle>
```

I would like to generate some random points within the circle element by using javascript or d3. I thought about the right approach to apply. And I come to the conclusion that I can do it in 2 ways:

- by generate just n random point coordinates cx,cy and then check if each point is within the svg circle if the distance from it to the center is at most the radius of circle element.
- by generate the radius of the point as `R * sqrt(random())` and the theta as `random() * 2 * PI` and calculate cx,cy as `r * cos(theta)` and `r * sin(theta)`.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: depends on the type of distribution you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using @Joseph O'Rourke idea to draw 1500 points. Alternatively you may create a single circle and reuse it.

Also if you don't need to use those points you may consider svg patterns

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let R = 50;
let c = { x: 50, y: 50 };

let g = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "g");

for (let i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
  let a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;// angle
  let r = Math.sqrt(~~(Math.random() * R * R));// distance fron the center of the main circle
  // x and y coordinates of the particle
  let x = c.x + r * Math.cos(a);
  let y = c.y + r * Math.sin(a);
  // draw a particle (circle) and append it to the previously created g element.
  drawCircle({ cx: x, cy: y, r: 1 }, g);
}

function drawCircle(o, parent) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "circle");
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}
//append the g element to the svg
svg.appendChild(g);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid; 
  max-width: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
```

Comment: Both answers were great. but this one has also a practical example scenario of application. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your second method does not produce a uniform distribution inside the circle.
See the left image below.

This process goes under the name "[disk point-picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)."
See that article to achieve the right image below

---

[image: Mathworld]

Image from Mathworld.

---